# After ABC ... XYZ?

Tags: feature-request

Feature request: Once we have ABC markup rendering for musical excerpts in posts, the *killer app* for this would be a site-wide **thematic index** of posts. A montage of single measures of music, and you click and it's either a question about the bit of music, or an example or something.

Index the Music

s'ilvousplait

Comment: Interesting - wonder how challenging that would be...

Answer (score 2):

How would such an index even be sorted? First note name A - G, then A# - G#, then Ab - Gb, then largest note value to smallest? What about grace notes? Pickup measures (do they count as first note or not)? What if you wanted to search by time signature? Or key signature? Would we index it in multiple ways? It seems like a huge and complex app to bolt on to a site that's part of a larger network that would only serve this one stack.

Even if we were able to index it all, how useful would that really be? In my head, I'm thinking most ABC markups would be examples, that would be plenty likely to be completely abstract and not an excerpt from anything, and short enough excerpts are likely to be meaningless out of context.

I notice that IMSLP does have a [Search by Melody](http://imslp.org/wiki/IMSLP:Search_by_Melody) feature. So there is one way to organize music. I'm still not sure I see how something like that could be useful here.

Comment: For anyone curious, I just tried putting in the first six notes or so of the Ode to Joy in the IMSLP melody search and one of the hits was Beethoven symphony number 9, so it seems to kind of work.

Comment: Sort by key, first note, usual post criteria (active/oldest/votes), *busyness?* I'm just saying that such a thing becomes *possible* now, and would be awesome. Perhaps also a line/grid option, where lines would show multiple measures (if available).